# Comparable interface Q

Tags: java, methods, comparable

I am a Java beginner, now studying the comparable interface. I meet a question. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot^_^

Here is the example in my Java video course.
The author maybe tries to override the compareTo, and compare the area of a shape (It should be a class) to the other shape. (obj)

```
public abstract class Shape implements Comparable{
    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        final double EPSILON = 1.0e-15; // Slightly bigger than machine precision
        Shape rhs = (Shape)obj;
        double diff = area() - rhs.area();
        if (Math.abs(diff)<=EPSILON*Math.abs(area()))
            return 0; // area of this shape equals to area of obj
        else if (diff<0)
            return -1; // area of this shape less than area of obj
        else 
            return 1; // area of this shape greater than area of obj
    }
}
```

After reading this, I only have a partial picture of how the Comparable interface works. Therefore, I try to write my own compareTo.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private String myPassword;
    private double myBalance;

    public BankAccount() {

    } // default constructor 

    public BankAccount(String password, double balance) {
        myPassword = password;
        myBalance = balance;
    } // constructor 

    public double compare(Object obj){
        BankAccount theOther= (BankAccount)obj;
        double diff = myBalance() - theOther.myBalance;
        return diff;
    } //the "compareTo" I wrote

}
```

However, the computer says that myBalance is not defined in BankAccount.
And I delete the "()" after myBalance.

```
double diff = myBalance - theOther.myBalance;
```

It works.

Therefore my question is why the "()" after myBalance is decisive for whether the program will run correctly. I mean but in the author's example, the "area" is still followed "()".

I guess maybe because the example is only a part of the codes, there is a method `private double area(){return area;}`hiding behind, and this allows the "area()" works. If I add

```
private double myBalance() {
    return myBalance;
}
```

My program will also run correctly with the "BankAccount()" right?
Thanks a lot. Looking forward someone to reply. ^_^

Comment: `()` in `myBalance()` means you are truing to call `myBalance` *method* with no parameters. Since you didn't have such method compiler couldn't find it and you ware informed about it in error message.

Comment: But honestly consider starting learning Java from a book ("head first java" or "thinking in Java" are quite nice) or official tutorial instead of video-tutorials. Such videos mostly are not created by experts and often don't contain full information required to understand subject, or have mistakes which will make you spend more time figuring them out then learning from proper source.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax with the parentheses — `area()`, `rhs.area()` and `myBalance()` — refer to *methods* with those names. So I suppose the `Shape` class in the video has an `area` method (conventionally it should have been named `getArea`, but whoever writes a method can call it what s/he wants). This also explains why adding a `myBalance` method to your `BankAccount` makes it work.

`myBalance` without the parantheses, on the other hand, refers to a *variable* by this name, so should be used if you haven’t got the method.

Allow me to add two things you didn’t ask about.

Is the video very old? It uses the so-called *raw* `Comparable`. This was how one did up to Java version 1.4.x. Today we are using 1.8 (usually just called 8) and some of us are trying Java 9 out. From Java 5 you should use so-called generics and extend `Comparable<Shape>` rather than just `Comparable`. It has some advantages that I won’t explain here, you can either take my word for it or go searcing.

If the purpose of your `BankAccount` class was to get to know the `Comparable` interface better, there are some changes you should make:

- The class should be declared to implement `Comparable<BankAccount>` (or just `Comparable` like `Shape` from the video if you want the old-fashioned way).
- Your method should be named `compareTo` (not just `compare`) and it should return an `int`.

Here’s how one would typically write the method these days:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(BankAccount theOther) {
    return Double.compare(myBalance, theOther.myBalance);
} // the "compareTo()", modernized
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rules to use Comparable:

The class should always be declared with implements Comparable.

It should always implement the method:

int compareTo(T o)

of the Comparable interface

The name compareTo is required and it can return int only, not double.

So I would suggest using the code below for your BankAccount class:

BankAccount.java

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable {
    private String myPassword;
    private double myBalance;

    public BankAccount() {

    } // default constructor 

    public BankAccount(String password, double balance) {
        myPassword = password;
        myBalance = balance;
    } // constructor 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        BankAccount theOther= (BankAccount)obj;
        double diff = myBalance - theOther.myBalance;
        if (diff > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (diff < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 

    public String getMyPassword() {
        return myPassword;
    }

    public void setMyPassword(String myPassword) {
        this.myPassword = myPassword;
    }

    public double getMyBalance() {
        return myBalance;
    }

    public void setMyBalance(double myBalance) {
        this.myBalance = myBalance;
    }
}// class
```

Then you can test it using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
    BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount();

    account1.setMyBalance(2000.45);

    account2.setMyBalance(2000.70);

    if (account1.compareTo(account2) < 0) {
        System.out.println("less"); 
    } else if (account1.compareTo(account2) > 0) {
        System.out.println("more");
    } else {
        System.out.println("equal");
    }
}
```

This approach already works. A cleaner approach is to implement Comparable<BankAccount> instead. Then you can get rid of the casting to BankAccount in compareTo implementation:

BankAccount.java

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount> {
    private String myPassword;
    private double myBalance;

    public BankAccount() {

    } // default constructor 

    public BankAccount(String password, double balance) {
        myPassword = password;
        myBalance = balance;
    } // constructor 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BankAccount obj){
        BankAccount theOther= obj;
        double diff = myBalance - theOther.myBalance;
        if (diff > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (diff < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 

    // getter and setters as before
}
```

Here is a reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Dominique Ubersfeld